# API design - what's the best way to respond useful error messages with 400s?

Tags: http-headers, api-design

I'm designing an API to be as HTTP compliant as I can. This includes sending specific response codes back and using the `Accept` header to specify versions and response types.

I understand this may appear subjective, but I'm sure there's a conventional way of doing this. I have a set of response types that the API supports, along with a vendor-specific mime type to specify the type and version.

Currently, when the client specifies a non-existent version or type, I'm just returning a `400 Bad Request` with an empty body, however, I want to return a useful error message. In the event that I don't know the response type, I feel a bit dirty responding with plain text (or defaulting to JSON). Is there a header I'm missing, or some convention that I should follow? I want to get this one right from the offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the status code of 406 Not Acceptable.

Comment: Great, that'll have to do. I'll add explicit instructions in the documentation that an incorrect version or content type will result in an HTTP 406. Cheers, Micheil.

Answer (score 2):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891/

This is a list of HTTP sub-codes supported by Microsoft IIS.  I've found this page damn handy since it gives you some insight into the messages they use to handle various errors.  There are some HTTP sub-codes that refer to headers.